# How can I pass data from a parent view controller to an embedded view controller in Swift?

Tags: swift, storyboard

I have a view controller embedded in another VC.
I would like to get the value of a variable from the main VC inside the embedded one. Specifically, I would like to change the text of label2 based on the value of label1.

I tried with "prepareForSegue", but it seems it's not triggered for embedded view controllers. I tried to isolate the problem in a test project:

[image]

Code for main VC:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label1.text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

Code for embedded VC:

```
class EmbeddedVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
 }
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This is not an embedded system. Read tag descriptions before adding them to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A way to achiеve this is to get the child view controller instance in the parent's viewDidLoad. It appears that the parent's viewDidLoad: gets called after the child's viewDidLoad:, which means the label is already created in the child's view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let childVC = self.childViewControllers.first as? ChildVC {
        childVC.someLabel.text = "I'm here. Aye-aye."
    }   
}
```

Comment: Cruz solution is working either, but this one seems more strait forward, thanks ;)

Answer (score 8):

First of all you can't set directly EmbeddedVC's lable2.text In `prepareForSegue`

because call sequence following below

1. MainVC's `prepareForSeque` this time EmbeddedVC's label2 is nil
2. EmbeddedVC's `viewDidLoad` called then label2 loaded
3. MainVC's `viewDidLoad` called then label1 loaded

so if you assign `MainVC's label1.text` to `EmbeddedVC's label2.text` in `prepareForSeque`
both label1 and label2 are nil so did not work

There are two way to solve this question

First Solution
MainViewController has EmbeddedVC and when MainVC's `viewDidLoad` called, assign label1.text to embeddedVC.label2.text

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    var embeddedVC: EmbeddedViewController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label1.text = "Hello"
        embeddedVC?.label2.text = label1.text
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let embeddedVC = segue.destination as? EmbeddedViewController {
            self.embeddedVC = embeddedVC
        }
    }
}

class EmbeddedViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Second Solution, use protocol and get MainVC's label text when viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear (later viewDidLoad called)

```
protocol EmbeddedVCDelegate: class {
    func labelText() -> String?
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, EmbeddedVCDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    // MARK: EmbeddedVCDelegate
    func labelText() -> String? {
        return label1.text
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label1.text = "Hello"
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let embeddedVC = segue.destination as? EmbeddedViewController {
            embeddedVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

class EmbeddedViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    weak var delegate: EmbeddedVCDelegate? = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        label2.text = delegate?.labelText()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution, but **embeddedVC** should be marked as `weak`. The MyViewController already owns it. There is no need for 2 owners.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to use prepareForSegue like this:

```
if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        guard let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? VC2 else { return }

        destinationViewController.label2.text = mytext
    }
```

Where the segue identifier you assign in storyboard

Comment: This should be the right solution. It's the most direct and has the effect the OP intended